# How to parse html forms in the Go Iris framework?

Tags: forms, post, go

Sorry if this question is a bit basic, but how can you parse form inputs in the Go Iris framework?
Here is the form I am using

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    Username:<input type="text" name="username">
    Password:<input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

here is the route and the controller respectively

```
iris.Post("/", TestController)
func TestController(c *iris.Context){

    username := c.Form.Get("username")//Doesn't work
    password := c.Form.Get("password")//Doesn't work

}
```

how do I retrieve the values in the Post request after the form has been submitted, Thanks

Comment: I'm not super familiar with that framework but on their github they have an example that does `c.PostValue("Username")` - that might do the trick for you. It could also just be your casing though. I bet those are `Username` and `Password`.

Comment: Awesome it worked thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, I'm go ahead and answer the question with that.

Comment: You can also do that with c.FormValue("Username")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off an example on the `iris` github page you could try `c.PostValue("Username")`. The code you have may also work but I think you need to capitalize the variable names. In the html template you can see the `name` value is lowercased, however your context is more likely going off those the variable names to the left of the actual html like `Username`.